# How to insert an item if not exists the one with the same name?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm inserting a batch of names:

```
myCollection.InsertBatch(value.Split(',').Where(o=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o)).Select( o => new Client { Name = o.Trim() }));
```

How to insert only the ones, that don't have the same Name?

p.s. Are MongoInsertOptions useful in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make unique index on "Name"

```
for example, in shell: db.MyCollection.ensureIndex({"Name":1}, {unique = true})
```

Add InsertOptions

```
var options = new MongoInsertOptions (myCollection) { CheckElementNames = true, Flags = InsertFlags.ContinueOnError, SafeMode = SafeMode.True};

var res = myCollection.InsertBatch(value.Split(',').Where(o => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(o)).Select(o => new Client { Name = o.Trim() }), options);
```